# Client_id showing only in Admin user of tree view but not showing in other Group user except Name field

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am new to openerp, In my customize module client_id,name other fields are showing only in Admin user of tree view but not showing in other Group user except Name field.

Answer (score 0):

field
defines a column where the corresponding field should be displayed for each record. Can use the following attributes:

**name:**
the name of the field to display in the current model. A given name can only be used once per view

**string:**
the title of the field's column (by default, uses the string of the model's field)

**invisible:**
fetches and stores the field, but doesn't display the column in the table. Necessary for fields which shouldn't be displayed but are used by e.g. @colors

**groups:**
**lists the groups which should be able to see the field**

**widget:**
alternate representations for a field's display. Possible list view values are:

**attrs:**
dynamic attributes based on record values. Only effects the current field, so e.g. invisible will hide the field but leave the same field of other records visible, it will not hide the column itself.